# correlation computation with threshold in R

Tags: r, correlation

I would like to compute correlations in R. However I have a lot of missing values. So, I would like to admit in the correlations matrix only correlations that were calculated from at least 10 pairs of values.
How to proceed?

Edit:
please note that correlation matrix is generated from two big matrices X and Y having same individuals (rows).

Comment: I don't understand your edit. You can easily convert from a data.frame to a matrix using `as.data.frame` and vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

First we generate some example data:

```
R> x = matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=5)
##Fill in some NA's
R> x[3:15,1] = NA
R> x[2:10,3] = NA
```

Next we loop through the `x` matrix doing a comparsion to detect NA's:

```
##Create a matrix with where the elements are the
##maximum number of possible comparisons 
m = matrix(nrow(x), ncol=ncol(x),nrow=ncol(x)) 
## This comparison can be made more efficient. 
## We only need to do column i with i+1:ncol(x)

## Each list element
for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    detect_na = is.na(x[,i]==x)
    c_sums = colSums(detect_na)
    m[i,] = m[i,] - c_sums
}
```

The matrix `m` now contains the number of comparison for each column pair. Now convert the `m` matrix in preparation of subsetting:

```
 m = ifelse(m>10, TRUE, NA)
```

Next we work out the correlation for all column pairs and subset according to `m`:

```
R> matrix(cor(x, use = "complete.obs")[ m], ncol=ncol(m), nrow=nrow(m))
     [,1]    [,2]     [,3]    [,4]    [,5]
[1,]   NA      NA       NA      NA      NA
[2,]   NA  1.0000 -0.14302 0.35902 -0.3466
[3,]   NA -0.1430  1.00000 0.03949  0.6172
[4,]   NA  0.3590  0.03949 1.00000  0.1606
[5,]   NA -0.3466  0.61720 0.16061  1.0000
```

Comment: However your solution takes too much time for big matrices

Comment: I didn't think you would have a problem with big matrices since your criteia was to have a least **10** observations. If you have lots of columns, you could remove columns where there are fewer than ten observations before the loop.